# How can i make 2 forms in seperate projects access and .Show() each other without circular dependency

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, circular-dependency, multiple-projects

### LoginInfo Class

I have a `LoginInfo` class which gets and sets the Username of the user logging to track the current user in multiple forms or projects.

```
public class LoginInfo
{
    public static string Username = "NoLoginDetected";
    public static void SetLoginData(string un)
    {
        Username = un;
    }
    public static string GetLoginData()
    {
        return Username;
    }
}
```

### The User entity

```
public class User:EntityBase
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Username{ get; set; } 
    public string Password{ get; set; } 

    public string UserType { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have Multiple Projects but we can divide them into 2 Main parts.

### 1- Login Module

This Project contains the login form which references the other modules and depending on the login authorization it leads to the corresponding module's Main Form. Also sets the username with `LoginInfo.SetLoginData(username);` if login succeeds.

(ex. The user logging has the UserType = "Designer" -> Leads to the Designer module Main Menu )

### 2- User-authorization dependent modules/projects.

- **Designer Module**

Contains a Main Menu with certain tasks for the designer.

- **Admin Module**

Contains a Main Menu with certain tasks for the admin.

---

And few more modules like those above.

I can access the other modules from the login form with the basic

```
FormDesigner frm = new FormDesigner(); 
frm.ShowDialog();
```

But i also want to prevent access to those modules, if by any chance those other projects or their forms were loaded outside the access from the login formm and if thats the case redirect the user to the login form.
The issue is, my Login project already references these other projects so i cannot add the login project as a referance to them because of circular dependency.

```
// - Designer or Admin Main Form

if(LoginInfo.GetLoginData() == "NoLoginDetected")
{ 
MessageBox.Show("No login detected. Redirecting to the login page..."); 
this.Hide();
// ---  HERE IS THE ISSUE  ------
FormLogin frmLogin = new FormLogin(); 
frmLogin.ShowDialog();
// Because i cannot add a referance to the Login Project since it causes Circular Dependency 
this.Close();
 }
```

**Summary**

My goal is to be able to login to the other modules by a single login form/project depending on the privileges of the user logging in while also preventing access to the other modules if they get accessed without a login thus leading back to the login form.

Comment: seems you need some `Events`.

Comment: You can create another project, which referenced to both projects, and should have Show function for each of the forms

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

1. Add one project (eg. project A) as reference of the other (project B). Then you can call the A window from the B project.
2. Create a static Window variable in project A. Save the B window into the A variable. Now project A can show projec B's window.

If you need to use some more methods or fields/property, then try with Reflection.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will check out reflection. For the suggestion with static variable i dont know how to save the B window into the A variable without having a reference of the B window. I could use a constructer but the same rule applies on it too because i need to access the B window inside A even if only A was initialized/invoked. So i cant get the B window without a referance when A initializes itself.

Comment: When you create the A window from the B project, you can save the B window into the static A variable